# Delphi calling SQL Server Stored Procedure slow

Tags: sql-server, delphi, stored-procedures

I'm stumped. In SSMS, when I execute a Stored Procedure with parameters, the procedure takes 6 seconds.  When being executed from a Delphi program (with the same parameters) the procedure takes 26 seconds to run.  I ran SQL Profiler and ran Devart's DBMonitor and it only confirms that the time is in fact 26 seconds.

Just to be sure that I'm comparing apples with apples, I clean the environment and the cache before executing in both cases...

The procedure has 7 optional parameters (with default values) all varchar's.

Can anyone guide me to find where the problem can be coming from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what client are you using for the sql connection? (OLEDB, native client, ...)

Comment: @whosrdaddy Since I'm not the one that created the Delphi program (I'm more of a DBA) I'm not sure but I think it's SDAC (does that make sense? LOL)

Comment: I think this might be a parameter sniffing issue. I'm reading about it now.

Comment: Canonical reading: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: @Alex K. thank you... Reading it now.

Comment: is the dataset bound to any controls, if so, it could be a control issue..

Comment: Does the SP return a result set and if so how many rows?

Comment: @John Easley I don't think it uses any controls (as I said I'm not a Delphi programmer) All the procedure does is take data from one table and updates another table depending on parameter values.

Comment: @MartynA no result sets are returned. Data is taken from one table, manipulated and updated or inserted into another table.

Comment: @Alex K great article up until now... I've read a quarter of the article... tried to apply the local variable idea but no difference yet.  I will continue reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Alex K.'s comment +1 which led me to the [Slow in application Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) I was able to pin point the issue. 
Although the article is 30 pages - it took 7 pages to understand and solve the issue.

The 2 most common problems found are Parameter sniffing and Different options that are Set that the application sets for running queries.

After copying the parameter values into local variables of the procedure to avoid parameter sniffing, which didn't change the behavior, I looked at different options that are set in the application,  such as:
ArithAbort, ansi_warnings,concat_null_yields_null, etc.

The problem that we were having in our application, is that the Application running in Delphi sets a bunch of options before starting: ArithAbort off, ansi_warnings off... including concat_null_yields_null OFF

The one that was causing the problem in my case is concat_null_yields_null OFF
when running in SSMS (by default) concat_null_yields_null is ON.

I now need to figure out how this option being ON/OFF affects a stored procedure.